# If a monster attacks in a forest, does it take a click?

Tags: dont-starve

While playing Don't Starve, I occasionally find myself doing battle in a forest - usually while killing Spiders for their luscious silk and glands. The trouble comes when I'm wielding a weapon, and my character would rather discuss the local flora than actually attack the spider that's trying to carve me into steaks.

Specifically, when I'm trying to click on a partially-concealed spider to attack, or else click elsewhere so I can run away terribly fast, I accidentally click on a tree. This makes Wilson tell me that trees are piney — and then take damage from the spider that's chasing him. Is there a way to issue commands so that I attack the nearest critter or move to a location, to prevent the sorts of mistakes that get me killed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can avoid most of this problem by using the keyboard.

Instead of moving with the mouse, use the WASD keys, especially in a cluttered environment. During a fight, you can hold the F key. This will cause you to automatically move towards and attack the nearest enemy.

Comment: Is there a way to cycle through which enemy you want to attack?  If not, it would make an awesome mod for someone with better programming skills than I!

Comment: Or to perhaps attack the monster closest to the cursor?

Comment: Note the difference between 'F' (attack a hostile creature, in a fight) and CTRL-F (attack the nearest creature, even when not in a fight)